# Jquery Computed CSS Not Applying?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Html:

```
<div class="warframe_option">
<div class="w1 woption"></div>
<div class="w2 woption"></div>
<div class="w3 woption"></div>
<div class="w4 woption"></div>
<div class="w5 woption"></div>
<div class="w6 woption"></div>
<div class="w7 woption"></div>
<div class="w8 woption"></div>
<div class="w9 woption"></div>
<div class="w10 woption"></div>
<div class="w11 woption"></div>
<div class="w12 woption"></div>
<div class="w13 woption"></div>
<div class="w14 woption"></div>
<div class="w15 woption"></div>
<div class="w16 woption"></div>
<div class="w17 woption"></div>
<div class="w18 woption"></div>
<div class="w19 woption"></div>
<div class="w20 woption"></div>
<div class="w21 woption"></div>
<div class="w22 woption"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$top = 0;
$left = 0;
for(var i = 1; i < 23; i++) {
    $('.w' + i).css("background", "url(" + window.myNamespace['w' + i].image +") no-repeat");

    if(i >= 2) {
        $('.w' + i).css("position", "relative");
        $('.w' + i).css("top", $top + "%");
        $('.w' + i).css("left", $left + "%");
    }

    $top = $top - 44;
    $left = $left + 12;
}
```

Css:

```
.woption {
    background-size:100%;
    width:10%;
    border-radius:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

The problem is that it computes everything correctly, but then it doesn't show up. I get no errors in google chrome's console so I don't know why this won't work.

Comment: You are probably missing a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` wrap around your code

Comment: No, I'm affraid that is is already in place I just didn't show it in the snippet of code I put on here.

Comment: Reproduce it in a fiddle for us please.

Comment: If everything is computing I assume that to mean the JQuery is running and that would mean the code is wrapped and referances the correct JQuery file. What is not showing up - the DIVs or the images?

Comment: It works perfectly in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/0nyykymy/). I added a height of 10px so you can actually see the results.

Comment: Really, no error, because I am getting an error from the "window.myNamespace['w'+i].image".  You have an issue regarding the images that you are trying to pull in for the background images.  Also, since the script isn't pulling in the proper background images, the DIV heights are 0px and not showing up.

Comment: I can't reproduce my website in a fiddle, I have a few resources that I use that I can't reproduce there for privacy reasons (I don't want to release it yet). I see how it works on the js fiddle, but that doesn't help my problem. Like I said I'm not sure why they don't show up - I get no error message.

Comment: @Michael I see now that the x should be an i, but it still doesn't work when I changed that

Comment: open up Chrome's console and check the height of each div.  If the height is 0px and you have no errors (you're window.myNamespace is working correctly with your resources), then the divs might be working, just with 0 height.